# Centering div inside a background image div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a image that will stretch with the browser. I have a div that's a logo when the wrapper div(image) is shrunk the div should stay centered but its off to one side . I used left:42%; to center. It its fine when big just when u shrink it goes off to one side..

Do I have any other options besides left:42%;? margin: 0 auto; did not work...

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(jewler/Allura-Regular.otf);
}
body {
 b111ackground-color: #000000;
}

 h1 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
  h2 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
 h3 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#wrapper{
 width:80%;
 height:80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 ;
 }
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#logo{
 
margin: 0 auto;
border: px solid green;
color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
display:table;
width:21%;

max-width:250px;
height:122px;
top:0%;
left:42%;

}


#info{
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid green;
color:#FFF;
display:table;
width:250px;
height:250px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> | Coming Soon!</title>




</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<IMG SRC="jewler/BackGround.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>


<div id="logo">
<IMG SRC="jewler/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</div>





<div id="info">
Coming Soon
Adress:
Phone:
E-mail:
</div>





</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would go left:`50%;` and `margin-left` " - half the div size " IE if the `div` was `100px` I'd make `margin-left:-50px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left: 50%` with `transform: translateX(-50%)` to center an absolutely positioned element horizontally. Also remove the left margin so it's truly centered.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(jewler/Allura-Regular.otf);
}
body {
 b111ackground-color: #000000;
}

 h1 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
  h2 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
 h3 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#wrapper{
 width:80%;
 height:80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 ;
 }
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#logo{
 
margin: 0 auto;
border: px solid green;
color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
/* margin-left:10px; */
margin-top:10px;
display:table;
width:21%;

max-width:250px;
height:122px;
top:0%;
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);

}


#info{
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid green;
color:#FFF;
display:table;
width:250px;
height:250px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> | Coming Soon!</title>




</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<IMG SRC="jewler/BackGround.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>


<div id="logo">
<IMG SRC="jewler/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</div>





<div id="info">
Coming Soon
Adress:
Phone:
E-mail:
</div>





</div>



</body>
</html>
```